# Selecting where timestamp greater than with timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have this table structure:

```
                          Table "test"
     Column     |            Type             | Modifiers
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 uuid           | uuid                        | not null
 created        | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

How would I select records after a certain date? But also factor in a specific timezone?

Since `created` is timestamp without zone, we can assume it's `UTC`

Example query:

`select uuid from test where created >= '2017-07-20'`

This would return all events that happend on, or after `2017-07-20 00:00:00.000 UTC` How would I query for events that happend after say, `2017-07-20 00:00:00.000 GMT+2` ? Without having to add hours to my argument in `created > arg`

Comment: I guess its not possible.

Comment: @Arijit You should only make that statement if you're almost 100% certain of it :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
select uuid
from test
where created > '2017-07-20'::timestamp with time zone at time zone '+02';
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  The Postgres documentation does not apppear to have anything like this in writing, in one place.

Comment: Awesome! I love postgres when it's so easy to read the actual sql :)

Comment: What happens when we want something in a few minutes or hours range, like "2019-09-11 00:12:01" and "2019-09-11 20:12:01"?

Comment: Ok, this worked for me: select whatever_column FROM some_table WHERE time_column > '2019-09-11 00:12:01'::TIMESTAMP AND time_column < '2019-09-11 20:12:01'::TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

I think one approach would be to compare the number of seconds since the epoch between your UTC timestamp in the table and some other input:

```
select uuid
from test
where
    extract(epoch from created) >
    extract(epoch from timestamp with time zone
            '2017-07-19 23:59:59.999'::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'GMT')
```

The above syntax is verbose, and there may be a shorter way of writing this query.  As a general rule, when you find yourself jumping through hoops to answer simple queries, it might mean you need to change your design.  If you were storing your timestamps in UTC and running queries from an application, you would probably be passing in local timestamps already converted to UTC, which would make things much simpler.

Comment: Yeah, it's what we're doing. However someone asked me to data-mine some stuff and i completely forgot that `created` was an UTC timestamp, and the client wanted stuff that happend after a certain date (GMT+2).
But thanks for the answer man! I'll try it out :)